# Como passar variável do POST para o GET (methods) no flask python 3

Tags: flask

O código abaixo e o que esta dando errado, que queria passar a variável:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)
 


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/segunda', methods=['POST'])
def segunda():
    user = request.form.get('usuario')
    psw = request.form.get('senha')
    #print('nome: {}\nsenha: {}' .format(user, psw))
    return redirect('/terceira', user, psw)

@app.route('/terceira', methods=['GET'])
def terceira():
    msg = '''<h1>Nome: {}</h1>
    <p><h1>Senha: {}</h1></p>'''.format(user, psw)
    return msg
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000)
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como criar uma variável em uma route com o método POST e passar essa variável para outra route com o método GET.

Esse é o resultado que queria obter porém passando do POST para o GET:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, url_for, request

app = Flask(__name__)
 


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/segunda', methods=['POST'])
def segunda():
    user = request.form.get('usuario')
    psw = request.form.get('senha')
    #print('nome: {}\nsenha: {}' .format(user, psw))
    return '''<h1>Nome: {}</h1>
    <p><h1>Senha: {}</h1></p>'''.format(user, psw)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu consegui, se tiver alguém precisando, tá aqui o código:

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def segunda():
    user = request.form.get('nome')
    mail = request.form.get('email')
    tel = request.form.get('telefone')
    psw = request.form.get('senha')

    query = '''update usuario set ultimo_login=(SELECT DATE()) where id_usuario=?;'''

    url = '/terceira/'+str(user)+'/'+str(mail)+'/'+str(tel)
    return redirect(url)

@app.route('/terceira/<usuario>/<mail>/<tel>', methods=['GET'])
def terceira_func(usuario, mail, tel):

    return ''' <h1>Nome: {}</h1>
    <p><h1>Email: {}</h1></p>
    <p><h1>Telefone: {}</h1></p>
    '''.format(usuario, mail, tel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=4000)
```

o html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block head %}
<title>Task master</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<form action="/login" method="POST"> 
  <div class = "primeiro">
    <h1>Create account</h1>
  </div> 
    <div class="content">
      <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
      <p><input type="text" name="nome" ></p>
      <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
      <p><input type="text" name="email" ></p>
      <label for="psw"><b>Telefone</b></label>
      <p><input type="text" name="telefone" ></p>
      <label for="psw"><b>Senha</b></label>
      <p><input type="password" name="senha" ></p>
      <button type="submit">Criar</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score -4):

O método GET não aceita parâmetros.

Crie uma função e chame esta função passando os parâmetros adquiridos através do POST.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).